# Secure way of storing JWT secret key used to encode/decode token data

Tags: python, security, oauth-2.0, jwt, fastapi

I'm building a Python application using FastApi and I'm using JWT and OAuth2 password flow to authenticate the users, as specified in their documentation. When a user logs in it receives a token, generated with HS256 algorithm and a user secret key. This token is stored as local storage in the browser. Then for each request that depends on the current logged in user, the token is send to the backend, decoded using the same secret key and the needed information is provided. In my app I have a PostgreSQL database and my question is where should I store those secret keys used to generate tokens for different type of users that I have and to keep those keys secured.

Thank you

Comment: You dont have to keep a copy of JWT in the database, only the private key to verify the token. 
are you using multiple secrets keys ?

Comment: Yes. And keeping this secret key in the database is secure enough?

Comment: You should keep it in ENV variable on the production system to be able to regenerate them easily if needed

Comment: different type of users, mean role base authorization ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 yes, but at this point I focus on authentication

Answer (score 2):

A recommended approach is to:

- Create an `.env` file and store the `SECRET` in it
- Create one `settings.py` file in root folder of the project
- Import `SECRET` from `.env` to a variable in `settings.py` and use it